# R: How can I automatically insert all elements of an vector into a repeated function?

Tags: r

I'm working on textanalysis in R: from a table of words I only need to select specific words/rows and recombine them for further analysis.

At the moment I am using this R-code:

```
> head(liste)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   line Worte   
  <int> <chr>   
1     1 mir     
2     1 geht    
3     1 es      
4     1 total   
5     1 schlecht
6     2 das 

absliste <- rbind(
subset(liste,liste$Worte=="alles"),
subset(liste,liste$Worte=="total"),
subset(liste,liste$Worte=="voll"),
subset(liste,liste$Worte=="komplett")
)
```

The problem is, that the number of relevant words (all elements of a vector "Worte") is going to become very big so its a lot of work to type it all like this.

```
Worte
[1] "alles"    "total"    "komplett" "voll"
```

Is there a way to insert the elements of the vector "Worte" automatically into my previous code, so I don't have to type all the words separately?

I need to analyse the text in regard to every element of the vector.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `%in%` operator:

This won't work if your column and your vector have the same name, so switch that first:

```
Worte_vec <- Worte
rm(Worte)
absliste <- subset(liste,liste$Worte %in% Worte_vec)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly!